# Android RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

what's the Wrong 
this code for chat application .. messages not shown and ProgressDialog still in the screen

Adapter class

```
public class chatadaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<chatadaptor.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Message> messageList;

    public chatadaptor(Context mContext, List<Message> messageList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.messageList = messageList;
    }




    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv_time , tv_message_content;
        RadioButton statusradiobutton ;
        LinearLayout Rsenttext  ,Rresecivedtext;
        ImageView img_msg;
        RelativeLayout Rsentpic ,Rresecivedp ;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tv_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            tv_message_content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_message_content);
            Rsenttext = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Rsenttext);

            Rresecivedtext = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Rresecivedtext);

            Rsentpic = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Rsentpic);

            Rresecivedp = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Rresecivedp);


            img_msg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_msg);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatting,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);
        holder.Rresecivedtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_message_content.setText(message.getContent());
        Toast.makeText(mContext,message.getDegree() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }
}
```

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/Rresecivedtext"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_username"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/received_message">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:text=" مرحبا "
            android:textColor="@color/album_title" />


    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/container"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="12:20 AM"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Rsenttext"
    android:visibility="v"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="12:20 AM"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sent_message">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:text="  message text "
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And Activity

```
public void  getMessages(){
        progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.wait));
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setCancelable(true);

        progress.show();

        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String ADD_TOKEN_URL = "http://XXXXXXXXX/api/Chat.php";
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ADD_TOKEN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        if (response.trim().equals("1000")) {
                            Toast.makeText(userchats.this, "user error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }else if (response.trim().equals("1111")){
                            Toast.makeText(userchats.this, "sending error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            progress.dismiss();}
                        else {


                            response = response.substring(response.indexOf('\n')+1);
                            try {
                                String encodedstring = URLEncoder.encode(response, "ISO-8859-1");
                                response = URLDecoder.decode(encodedstring, "UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            }


                            try {

                                List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
                                Message message;
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                                JSONArray apparray = object.getJSONArray("chat");
                                for (int i = 0; i < apparray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject currentobject = apparray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String type = currentobject.getString("type");
                                    String content = currentobject.getString("content");
                                    String timestamp = currentobject.getString("timestamp");
                                    String degree = currentobject.getString("degree");

                                    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyAccount", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                                    String Uid = pref.getString("Uid", null); // getting String

                                    message = new Message( Uid, type, content, timestamp, degree);

                                    messageList.add(message);

                                    chatadaptor adapter = new chatadaptor(userchats.this , messageList);

                                    recyclerChat.setAdapter(adapter);


                                }


                              //  progress.dismiss();


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(userchats.this, "error in sending message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        progress.dismiss();


                    }
                })  {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyAccount", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                        String Uid = pref.getString("Uid", null); // getting String

                        params.put("action","view");
                        params.put("userid",Uid);
                        //params.put("type",lpasss);
                       // params.put("content",lpasss);
                     //   params.put("timestamp",lpasss);

                        return params;

                    }
                };
                Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext()).add(request);

            }
        };
        t.start();

    }
```

data come  from serve and converted to JSONObject `enter code here` correctly 
what's the Wrong 
this code for chat application .. messages not shown and ProgressDialog still in the screen

Comment: set your RecyclerView adapter outside the for loop.

Comment: Check your log you might get some crash in JSONException

Comment: i tried but still not working

Comment: no JSON error it work correctly

Answer (score 1):

just add following lines because you did not add layout manager for your recyclerview

```
recyclerChat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

hope this works for you..

Comment: can you post your xml file which has recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ServicesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    Context con;
    AtmHolder pvh1;
    List<serviceListData> serviceslist;
    public ServicesListAdapter(List<serviceListData> serviceslist, Context con) {
        this.serviceslist = serviceslist;
        this.con = con;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.services_list_item_style, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new AtmHolder(v);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof AtmHolder) {
            pvh1 = (AtmHolder) holder;
            pvh1.tv_service.setText(serviceslist.get(position).getName());
            Glide.with(con)
                    .load("image url")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.internet)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(pvh1.iv_service);
        }
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int a = 0;
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return serviceslist.size();
    }

    public static class AtmHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView iv_service;
        TextView tv_service;
        AtmHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_service = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_service);
            tv_service = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_service);
        }
    }
}
```